# is it possible to include hash (for example SHA-256) of document it the document

Tags: hash, digital-signature

For example I want to send text document with content:

```
---start of hello.txt---
Hello world!

SHA-256 hash of this document is: e5cefc21ce1131cc0e8759f5e3b46c016319883c6f9b0d714502f3cf7226864f
---end of hello.txt---
```

Comment: So you are asking if you could create a document with known text where `hash_as_hex(text + hexdigest) = hexdigest` ? What is the use case for this or is it just curiosity?

Comment: Are you trying to hash the document and then putting that same hash in the same document? It's like 'hashception'?

Comment: There is no standard way to do this for SHAs. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432669/chicken-egg-problem-hash-of-file-including-hash-inside-file-possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is a problem akin to that of the [self-enumerating pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram#Self-enumerating_pangrams), but since the hash function is not reversible, the only way of doing this is by brute force. Given the size of the key space, this is unfeasible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could potentially include a hash of the other content in the file in the file - e.g.

```
---START CONTENT---
some content
----END CONTENT---
Hash of CONTENT: sha256:aaaaf
```

It isn't clear what that achieves, though, because anyone able to intercept the message can replace both the content and hash - something using e.g. HMAC would prevent.